# How to validate SMTP through yii\swiftmailer\Mailer in Yii?

Tags: yii, smtp

I wanna validate SMTP credentials used are valid or not before sending an email.
I tried with `Yii::$app->mail->SmtpConnect()` but it's throwing an error.
How to validate SMTP in Yii?

Comment: I think that the only reliable way of testing SMTP configuration is trying to send test email.

Comment: @rob006, I accept, and I follow the same for now. looking forward is there any way other than sending an email